# Finding input values that meet target values at output

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am simulating a complex circuit which has

10 input variables,

```
I1,I2, ... ,I10
```

and 6 output variables,

```
Y1,Y2,...,Y6
```

i.e.

```
Y1 = f1(I1,I2,...,I10)
Y2 = f2(I1,I2,...,I10)
...
Y10 = f10(I1,I2,...,I10)
```

I don't know the equations that model their relationships. But, I can simulate the circuit to collect the following data to realize the relationship between an input and an output variable.

```
Y1 by varying I1 (keeping other inputs fixed)
Y1 by varying I2 (keeping other inputs fixed)
.....
```

then

```
Y2 by varying I1 (keeping other inputs fixed)
Y2 by varying I2 (keeping other inputs fixed)
... 
and so on.
```

Now, I have to find values `(I1,I2,....,I10)` such that the combination meets certain constraints for the outputs, for example,

```
Y1 > 10
Y2 < 5
Y3 > 6
Y4 > 8
Y5 < 2
Y6 > 12
```

Please help me with algorithm I should use here. 
I can keep the data in excel and run the algorithm in Matlab.
Sorry if the problem statement is not formal/clear. Thanks in advance :)